# Export data with parameter year and month Laravel + Mysql

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I got stack when i want to implement export data with parameters, this is the code from controller

```
public function export_byMonth(Request $request)
{
    return Excel::download(new ProjectMSelected($request->m , $request->y), 'ProjectMonthly_'.$request->m.'_'.$request->y.'.xlsx');
}
```

Note M is Month and Y = is Year

and this is the code for export using maatwebsite/excel.

```
namespace App\Exports;

use App\table2;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromCollection;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromQuery;
use Illuminate\Contracts\View\View;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromView;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\Exportable;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadings;

class ProjectMSelected implements FromView, WithHeadings
{
    use Exportable;

  public function __construct($m , $y)
  {
      $this->m = $m;
      $this->y = $y;
  }
  public function headings(): array
  {
   return [
      'Code Project' ,
      'Name',
      'Directorates',
      'Division', 
      'Scope',
      'Priority',
      'Progress',
      '%',
      'Remarks',
      'Plan',
      'pdate',
      'PM',
      'CO PM',
  ];
}
public function view(): View
{
    return view('report.excel.report_monthly_per_project', [
        'project_array' => table2::whereRaw('YEAR(tgl_masuk) = ',$this->y ,'And Month(tgl_masuk) =', $this->m)->get()
    ]);
}
}
```

it's still parsing the error message like this, how to solve the error ?

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1 (SQL: select * from `projectmonthlyview2` where Month(tgl_masuk) = YEAR(tgl_masuk) =)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How use this instead:

```
table2::whereRaw('YEAR(tgl_masuk) = ' . $this->y . ' AND MONTH(tgl_masuk) = ' . $this->m)->get()
```

Comment: still got error message, 

Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'And MONTH(tgl_masuk) =' at line 1 (SQL: select * from `projectmonthlyview2` where YEAR(tgl_masuk) = And MONTH(tgl_masuk) =)

Comment: Could you make sure $request->y and $request->m isn't null value?